# System messages in vim

Tags: shell, arch-linux, vim, stdout

O/S: Arch Linux (Kernel 4.3.3-2-ARCH)

---

While editing files with VIM 7.4 it occassionally happens that system messages appear on the screen, ruining my workflow but obviously not altering the contents of the file. The strings seem to be return values or error messages/warnings from other background processes (e.g. `thunderbird &`). Is there any way to suppress these? Additionally, I'd really like to know why this happens..

Comment: Please post some screenshots or at least the text of these messages, so that we can figure out where they might have come from. That could be messages from the kernel, `wall` messages, or output from programs running in the background. Did you by any chance start programs like Thunderbird with `thunderbird &` in your current shell before you started vim?

Comment: Ok. I'm trying to reproduce the behavior and will add a screenshot to my post as soon as it happens again. Yes, I started `thunderbird &` before I started vim.

Comment: Then that is the cause - any processes that you've started with `&` are still able to print output to your current console while they're running in the background. So whenever Thunderbird decides to output something, it ends up in the middle of your console. Redirecting STDOUT and STDERR might help: `thunderbird &> /dev/null &`. But the cleanest solution would be not to start GUI applications from the console, just start them from the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands started in a shell session will have `stdout` and `stderr` (standard output and error) connected to that session. You're starting Thunderbird manually (i.e. by typing `thunderbird &`, not by clicking an icon in a graphical user interface) so its messages to `stdout` and `stderr` will arrive in your current shell session regardless of what you're currently doing.

Two solutions springs to mind:

1. Start the application in another window (another shell session).
2. Redirect the standard streams to `/dev/null`:

   ```
   $ thunderbird >/dev/null 2>&1 &
   ```